# Login failed for user 'username'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqlconnection, sqlexception

I have a form that selects a bunch of rows from a table in my MSSQL server, now, this form is used to update data, which it does correctly, after I update the data using the form however, it redirects back to a page with a datagrid of all the rows in that table, and allows me to select another row to update, if I select the row I just updated again, I'm greeted with "Login failed for user 'slehan_ticketadmin'."

Now I know the username/password are correct, because I used the form a minute ago in order to update the data. I can't view the SQL Error Logs because my host limits me, but here is my code behind for the update form.

```
namespace YakStudios_Support.ys_admin
{
    public partial class UpdateTicket : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                int ticketID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ticketID"]); // Grabs the ?ticketid number from the URL
                Ticket ticketBeingUpdated = TicketDatabase.selectTicketFromDatabase(sqlErrorLabel, ticketID); // Creates a new Ticket object to be used by the form to populate the text boxes

                /* Form Field Population */
                // Email
                emailTxt.Text = ticketBeingUpdated.getEmail();

                // Date Submitted
                dateSubText.Text = ticketBeingUpdated.getDateSubmitted().ToString();

                // Ticket Class
                classDropDown.SelectedValue = ticketBeingUpdated.getTicketClass();

                // Ticket Status
                statusDrop.SelectedValue = ticketBeingUpdated.getStatus();

                // Subject
                subjectTxt.Text = ticketBeingUpdated.getSubject();

                // Text
                textTxt.Text = ticketBeingUpdated.getTicketContent();
            }
        }

        protected void editBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            emailTxt.Enabled = true;
            dateSubText.Enabled = true;
            classDropDown.Enabled = true;
            statusDrop.Enabled = true;
            subjectTxt.Enabled = true;
            textTxt.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ticketID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ticketID"]); // Grabs the ?ticketid number from the URL
            DateTime convertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateSubText.Text);
            Ticket ticketUpdated = new Ticket(emailTxt.Text, convertedDate, subjectTxt.Text, textTxt.Text, statusDrop.SelectedValue, classDropDown.SelectedValue);
            TicketDatabase.updateTicketInDatabase(ticketUpdated, sqlErrorLabel, ticketID);
            Response.Redirect("ticketqueue.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

The Ticket class you see, is just a class that holds the data for the tickets that are updated/selected/deleted from the SQL Server, it's just an easy way for me to modify/hold data in a structured way. I want to bring your attention to the line:

```
Ticket ticketBeingUpdated = TicketDatabase.selectTicketFromDatabase(sqlErrorLabel, ticketID);
```

I have another class called TicketDatabase that has a bunch of methods that insert/select/update/delete tickets from the database. Here is the selectTicketFromDatabase() method stub.

```
        public static Ticket selectTicketFromDatabase(Label sqlErrorLabel, int ticketID)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from yak_tickets");

        using (SqlConnection selSqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConn.ConnectionString))
        //using (sqlConn)
        {
            sqlCmd.Connection = selSqlConn;
            selSqlConn.Open(); // Open the SQL connection
            //sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            //sqlConn.Open(); // Open the SQL Connection

            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            Ticket ticketReturning = null; // Initializes the ticketReturning but it's not allocated

            // Call during reading
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                /* Objects to hold values from reader */
                string emailString = reader["email"].ToString();
                DateTime dateSubbed = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dateSubmitted"].ToString());
                string subjectString = reader["subject"].ToString();
                string textString = reader["ticketText"].ToString();
                string statusString = reader["statusid"].ToString();
                string classString = reader["ticketClass"].ToString();

                ticketReturning = new Ticket(emailString, dateSubbed, subjectString, textString, statusString, classString);
            }
            selSqlConn.Close();
            return ticketReturning;
        }
    }
```

I'm going to test this on a localhost server to see if it's the server or my code causing the error, but I'm still open to suggestions/support to this particular issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Random kooky question--is this in Chrome or any browser?  I've noticed that Chrome has some odd behaviors in certain circumstances regarding credentials...

Comment: I tried it in Internet Explorer and Safari, same result on both.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an error associated with a SQL login (not Windows Authentication related).

Open SSMS, try and open a query window with:

- "SQL Server Authentication"
- Login = "slehan_ticketadmin"
- Password = what you expect the password to be.

Does it fail?

If yes, here are *some* options (after connecting another way):

- locked out (check slehan_ticketadmin Security/Users node in SSMS)
- does not exists (see above)
- password has changed/is wrong (change it in Security/Users node)
- default database is different (should tell you in the error message)
- SQL Server is set to Windows Authentication only

If not, your app has the wrong credentials stored

Edit, after comment.

In a query window, right click, connection, change connection... reconnect to the same SQL Server instance using the 1st bullet point instruction list above.

Comment: I can't run that script, it says there is no stored procedure called Login.

Comment: Ah okay, yes, it allows me to login. The weird thing is, it does this, right after I update the row, before I update it, it works fine.

Comment: I used a local database instead, and it works perfectly, I can select, update, select again and it does it fine. This is really strange.